# Waiting for 20 seconds before continuing (permanent error)

Tags: pyrogram

the get_chat_history and egt_chat_members methods throw a permanent waiting error -Waiting for 20 (23,21,22,18) seconds before continuing. get_chat works fine. This error appeared a couple of days ago.

```
    async with tg_cl:
        while True:
            try:
                async for members in tg_cl.get_chat_members(target):
                    members_chat.append(members)
                    break
            except FloodWait as Err:
                print("Flood wait: {} seconds".format(Err.value))
                sleep(Err.value)
                continue
```

...............

```
    async with tg_cl:
        while True:
            try:
                if 'join' in chat:
                    info_chat = await tg_cl.join_chat(chat)
                else:
                    info_chat = await tg_cl.get_chat(chat)
                    async for messages in tg_cl.get_chat_history(chat, limit=1, offset_id=-1):
                        count_messages = messages.id
                    break
            except FloodWait as Err:
                print("Flood wait: {} seconds".format(Err.value))
                sleep(Err.value)
                continue
```

Comment: The actual problem is likely no_updates=False, wich will autoflood and will disable your bot from just getting the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyrogram already handles FloodWait errors on its own, you don't need to apply any logic yourself.

When setting up your [`Client` instance](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/client), you can set the `sleep_threshold`. This is the amount of time that Pyrogram will handle a FloodWait error on its own, without any logic needed from you. You can set it to an arbitrarily high value to not get any errors anymore. Keep in mind that Pyrogram will silently handle these errors itself and only print something like "waiting x seconds" in your output.

```py
list_of_members = []
for member in app.get_chat_members(chat_id):
    list_of_members.append(member.id)
print(list_of_members)
[123, 456, 789, ...]
```

Please note that in Channels you can only retrieve 200 members at a time, in chats only 10 000 (ten thousand), this is a hard limit by the Server.

See Pyrogram's documentation on the available arguments, as well as some examples:

- https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_chat_members